# Cumulative Count Paste

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataset:

```
  ID Set Type Count
1  1   1    A    NA
2  2   1    R    NA
3  3   1    R    NA
4  4   1    U    NA
5  5   1    U    NA
6  6   1    U    NA
7  7   2    A    NA
8  8   3    R    NA
9  9   3    R    NA
```

As `dputs`:

```
mystart <- structure(list(ID = 1:9, Set = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("A", "R", "U"), class = "factor"), Count = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "Set", "Type", 
"Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

By using `dplyr` package how can I obtain this:

```
  ID Set Type  Count
1  1   1    A     A1
2  2   1    R   A1R1
3  3   1    R   A1R2
4  4   1    U A1R2U1
5  5   1    U A1R2U2
6  6   1    U A1R2U3
7  7   2    A     A1
8  8   3    R     R1
9  9   3    R     R2
```

Again `dputs`:

```
myend <- structure(list(ID = 1:9, Set = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("A", "R", "U"), class = "factor"), Count = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("A1", "A1R1", "A1R2", 
"A1R2U1", "A1R2U2", "A1R2U3", "R1", "R2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Set", "Type", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

---

In short, I want to count the observations of the column `"type"` within column `"set"` and print this `count(text)` cumulatively.

Examining similar posts, I got closely to this:

```
myend <- structure(list(ID = 1:9, Set = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("A", "R", "U"), class = "factor"), Count = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", "Set", "Type", 
"Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

With the code:

```
library(dplyr)
myend <- read.table("mydata.txt", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
    myend %>%
    group_by(Set, Type) %>%
    mutate(Count = seq(n())) %>%
    ungroup(myend)
```

Thank you very much for your help,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `dplyr` version:

```
mystart %>%
  group_by(Set) %>%
  mutate(Count = paste0('A', cumsum(Type == 'A'), 
                        'R', cumsum(Type == 'R'),
                        'U', cumsum(Type == 'U'))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Which yields

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
     ID   Set Type  Count 
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr> 
1     1     1 A     A1R0U0
2     2     1 R     A1R1U0
3     3     1 R     A1R2U0
4     4     1 U     A1R2U1
5     5     1 U     A1R2U2
6     6     1 U     A1R2U3
7     7     2 A     A1R0U0
8     8     3 R     A0R1U0
9     9     3 R     A0R2U0
```

---

If you want to omit the variables with count zero, you'd need to wrap a function around it like so

```
mygroup <- function(lst) {
  name <- names(lst)
  vectors <- lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) {
    x <- lst[[i]]
    char <- name[i]
    x <- ifelse(x == 0, "", paste0(char, x))
    return(x)
  })
  return(do.call("paste0", vectors))
}

mystart %>%
  group_by(Set) %>%
  mutate(Count = mygroup(list(A = cumsum(Type == 'A'),
                               R = cumsum(Type == 'R'), 
                               U = cumsum(Type == 'U')))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This yields

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
     ID   Set Type  Count 
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr> 
1     1     1 A     A1    
2     2     1 R     A1R1  
3     3     1 R     A1R2  
4     4     1 U     A1R2U1
5     5     1 U     A1R2U2
6     6     1 U     A1R2U3
7     7     2 A     A1    
8     8     3 R     R1    
9     9     3 R     R2
```

Answer (score 7):

Base R version :

```
aggregateGroup <- function(x){

  vecs <- Reduce(f=function(a,b){ a[b] <- sum(a[b],1L,na.rm=TRUE); a },
                 init=integer(0),
                 as.character(x), 
                 accumulate = TRUE)
  # vecs is a list with something like this :
  # [[1]]
  # integer(0)
  # [[2]]
  # A 
  # 1 
  # [[3]]
  # A R 
  # 1 1 
  # ...
  # so we simply turn those vectors into characters using vapply and paste 
  # (excluding the first)
  vapply(vecs,function(y) paste0(names(y),y,collapse=''),FUN.VALUE='')[-1]
}

split(mystart$Count,mystart$Set) <- lapply(split(mystart$Type,mystart$Set), aggregateGroup)

> mystart
  ID Set Type  Count
1  1   1    A     A1
2  2   1    R   A1R1
3  3   1    R   A1R2
4  4   1    U A1R2U1
5  5   1    U A1R2U2
6  6   1    U A1R2U3
7  7   2    A     A1
8  8   3    R     R1
9  9   3    R     R2
```

Comment: I liked this solution as its generic and does not depends on value of `Type`.

Answer (score 4):

One line solve with data.table

you gotta first do

```
require(data.table)
mystart <- as.data.table(mystart)
```

then just use one line

```
mystart[, .(Type,
            count = paste0(
              'A',
              cumsum(Type == 'A'),
              'R',
              countR = cumsum(Type == 'R'),
              'U',
              countU = cumsum(Type == 'U')
            )),
        by = c('Set')]
```

first you want cumsum each type and paste them together by 'set'

`cumsum(Type=='A')` equals the count, since when `Type==A`, it's 1, otherwise it's 0.

you wanted to paste them into one column also. So, `paste0()` is good to use.

you still wanted the `Type` column, so I included `Type` in the line.

The output:

```
   Set Type  count
1:   1    A A1R0U0
2:   1    R A1R1U0
3:   1    R A1R2U0
4:   1    U A1R2U1
5:   1    U A1R2U2
6:   1    U A1R2U3
7:   2    A A1R0U0
8:   3    R A0R1U0
9:   3    R A0R2U0
```

Hope this helps.

btw, if you want `count 0` ignored, you gotta design some if-esle clause yourself.

basically you want this: if `cumsum(something) ==0`, `NULL`, esle `paste0('something', cumsum(something))`, then you `paste0()` them together.

It's gonna get nasty, I'm not writing it. you get the idea

Answer (score 3):

Many elegant solutions have been provided for the problem. Still I was looking for something `dplyr` way (without-`cumsum` on fixed types). The function is generic enough to handle additional values of `Type`.

A solution with help of a `custom function` as:

```
library(dplyr)
mystart %>% group_by(Set, Type) %>%
  mutate(type_count = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(TypeMod = paste0(Type,type_count)) %>%
  group_by(Set) %>%
  mutate(Count = cumCat(TypeMod, type_count)) %>%
  select(-type_count, -TypeMod)


cumCat <- function(x, y){
  retVal <- character(length(x))
  prevVal = ""
  lastGrpVal = ""
  for ( i in seq_along(x)){
    if(y[i]==1){
      lastGrpVal = prevVal
    }
    retVal[i] = paste0(lastGrpVal,x[i])
    prevVal = retVal[i]     
  }
  retVal
}

# # Groups: Set [3]
#      ID   Set Type   Count 
#     <int> <int> <fctr> <chr> 
# 1     1     1 A      A1    
# 2     2     1 R      A1R1  
# 3     3     1 R      A1R2  
# 4     4     1 U      A1R2U1
# 5     5     1 U      A1R2U2
# 6     6     1 U      A1R2U3
# 7     7     2 A      A1    
# 8     8     3 R      R1    
# 9     9     3 R      R2
```

Comment: it seems your solution is conceptually similar to mine, but you're coding with a `loop` what really belong (in my opinion) in a `Reduce` call. You could also use `paste0` for better readability.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  Agree on use of `paste0`. Your solution is basically similar to one answer by @digEmAll. I wanted to keep it `dplyr` way based on `OP` expectation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base solution.

We can paste raw letters to`seq_along` of letter groups to get the last 2 characters, then `paste` the result to the last element of the previous result, using `Reduce`.

On top of this we use `ave` to compute by group.

```
fun <- function(x,y) paste0(x[length(x)],y,seq_along(y))

mystart$Count <- ave(as.character(mystart$Type),mystart$Set,
  FUN = function(x) unlist(Reduce(fun,split(x,x),init=NULL,accumulate = TRUE)))

#   ID Set Type  Count
# 1  1   1    A     A1
# 2  2   1    R   A1R1
# 3  3   1    R   A1R2
# 4  4   1    U A1R2U1
# 5  5   1    U A1R2U2
# 6  6   1    U A1R2U3
# 7  7   2    A     A1
# 8  8   3    R     R1
# 9  9   3    R     R2
```

**Details**

`split(x,x)` splits letters as shown here for first Set:

```
with(subset(mystart,Set==1),split(Type,Type))
# $A
# [1] "A"
# 
# $R
# [1] "R" "R"
# 
# $U
# [1] "U" "U" "U"
```

Then `fun` does this type of operations, helped by `Reduce` :

```
fun(NULL,"A")                        # [1] "A1"
fun("A1",c("R","R"))                 # [1] "A1R1" "A1R2"
fun(c("A1R1","A1R2"),c("U","U","U")) # [1] "A1R2U1" "A1R2U2" "A1R2U3"
```

**Bonus solution**

This other base solution, using `rle` and avoiding `split` gives the same output for given example (and whenever Type values are grouped in Sets), but not with `mystart2 <- rbind(mystart,mystart)` for instance.

```
fun2 <- function(x){
  rle_   <- rle(x)
  suffix <- paste0(x,sequence(rle_$length))
  prefix <- unlist(mapply(rep,
                          lag(unlist(
                            Reduce(paste0,paste0(rle_$values,rle_$lengths),accumulate=TRUE)
                          ),rle_$lengths[1]),
                          each=rle_$lengths))
  prefix[is.na(prefix)] <- ""
  paste0(prefix,suffix)
}

mystart$Count2 <-ave(as.character(mystart$Type), mystart$Set,FUN=fun2)
```